# What is the glue between Google Web Toolkit java files and the html

Tags: gwt

When I seek for information regarding GWT I find a lot of java examples. Then I installed the GWT on my computer and the sample it generates contains one HTML, that contains the basics of my page, and of course java files that controls it.

What is the glue between both? Is the HTML file the result of the compilation, so automatically generated by the framework and we only need to deal with the java file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT works by compiling those Java source files into JavaScript which your browser can run.

You write Java code supported by GWT and the GWT compiler will use that to create HTML and JS output that a web browser can use later. This compiler then, is your "glue" that binds the Java files and the final output.

Comment: However this glue can be customized using linkers, the default being the iframe linker. A linker is what takes the Javascript that is compiled from your Java code and does everything necessary to make it load and run.